# Where to find 7z dll?

Tags: c++, dll, 7zip

Hi I have been struggling for a while to figure out on where to find the 7Zip dll. Everyone talks about 7zip dll but I am not able to find out if it is already available for download or we should build it!! I have downloaded the LZMA SDK and also tried building it from path "CPP\7zip\UI\Client7z". I ended up with link errors as shown below. I am using VC6.0 to build the file. Can someone please guide me. FAQ / Google search didn't help.  I have used zlib earlier and it was pretty straight forward.

```
Linking...

FileStreams.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IStreamGetSize
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IStreamGetSize
FileStreams.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IInStream
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IInStream
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IOutStream
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IInArchive
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_CFormat7z
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IOutArchive
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_ICryptoGetTextPassword
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_ICryptoGetTextPassword2
Client7z.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IArchiveUpdateCallback2
```

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix - firing up google and feeding your error messages provides a whole bunch of alternatives, if that really doesn't fit.

Comment: @JensG Don't think so the OP is not asking about unresolved externals in general, but very specific for 7zip. The symbols he/she's missing look like COM interface UIDs and should come from some separate specification (MSIL compiled).

Comment: How about http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/e85ce0f1 ? Another two minutes googling.

Comment: @g-makulik you are right. More than those link errors, I am looking for builing 7zip. Unlike zlib, there isnt any clear details on how to build it / whether to build it? I looked at your link. Thanks for sharing. I would appreciate if you can help me understand how this DLL is built and is it readily available for download and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. 7Z dll can be found after installing 7zip software. Another alternative (which is a big headache) is to get the LZMA SDK and build it which I had no success. C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll would be the location of it. This sounds silly but it took me sometime to find it. Hope it might save some time for others who is using 7zip for the first time.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't answer your own question. The question asked was how to **build** the DLL, not where you can grab an existing one. Maybe you want to rephrase the question? Otherwise it would be misleading for people who hope to find an answer to that question here.

Comment: @JensG, thank you for correcting me. I will rephrase the problem statement. I had put both in problem statement "I have been struggling for a while to figure out on how to build the 7Zip dll." and then " Everyone talks about 7zip dll but I am not able to find out if it is already available for download or we should build it!!". I will edit the problem statement. Thanks